# Kafka : Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms with only one broker down

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have a kafka producer configured as -

```
metadata.broker.list=broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092,broker4:9092
serializer.class=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder
request.required.acks=1
request.timeout.ms=30000
batch.num.messages=25
message.send.max.retries=3
producer.type=async
compression.codec=snappy
```

`Replication Factor is 3 and total number of partition currently is 108`

Rest of the properties are default.

This producer was running absolutely fine. Then, due to some reason, one of the broker went down. Then, our producer started to show the log as -
`"Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms"`. Nothing else was there in the log and we were seeing this error. In some interval, few requests were getting blocked, even if producer was async.

This issue was resolved when the broker was again up and running.

What can be the reason of this? One broker down should not affect the system as a whole as per my understanding.

Comment: Are you still using the 0.8 producer?

Comment: @MickaelMaison Yes, the current version is 0.8.2.0. We are in process of upgrading. But, is this expected in this version?

Comment: @MickaelMaison If it is a bug in the kafka version 0.8.2.0., then is there any way to solve in that version temporarily? Could it happen if the broker is partition leader, so all request to that partition will fail? What setting can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer for someone who might face this issue -

The reason is older version of Kafka Producer. The kafka producers take bootstrap servers as list. In older versions, for fetching metadata, producers will try to connect with all the servers in Round Robin fashion. So, if one of the broker is down, the requests going to this server will fail and this message will come.

Solution:

- Upgrade to newer producer version.
- can reduce metadata.fetch.timeout.ms settings: This will ensure the main thread is not getting blocked and send will fail soon. Default value is 60000ms. Not needed in higher version

Note: Kafka send method is blocked till the producer is able to write to buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because I forgot to create the topic. Once I created the topic the issue was resolved.